# python json conversion to pipe delimited string performance issue

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to convert the list of jsons into list of pipe delimited strings. One of the problem that some json tags can be missed in some lines and the final list has to include ""|""|"" empty strings in place of missed tags. There is also no guarantee that every json will have same tags in same sequence. The number of pipe delimited strings has to remain the same. I changed json module to simplejson and use multiprocessing with strongs CPU's(32). But the result still poor. The use of pyinstaller doesn't improve anything. I definitely need community help.

Comment: Please provide your code, example input and expected output.

Comment: Well the first step to getting community help is to explain your problem clearly. Sharing your json and also the expected output structure would go a long way!!

Comment: I am so sorry, accidentally I found the solution: cjson.

Comment: Anyway many thanks and sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

I tested different json parsers: simplejson, ujson, json, yajl and nothing helped. Then I came into cjson and it decreased time from 28 minutes to 1.5 minutes. I have no idea "why?" but works like a rocket despite other solutions also implemented in "C".